# How can I prevent access to an Angular page if the user IS logged in with AngularFire?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I feel like this is really easy but I'm not sure why I can't figure it out.

For example if we want to restrict access to a page if a user is not logged in we can do something like:

```
// == LISTEN FOR ROUTE ERRORS
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, next, previous, error) {
        if (error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });
}]);

// == RETURN AUTH SERVICE
app.factory('Authentication', ['$firebaseAuth', function($firebaseAuth) {
    return $firebaseAuth();
}]);

// == APP ROUTER
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$location', function($routeProvider, $location) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/account', {
            controller: 'userController',
            templateUrl: 'views/account.html',
            resolve: {
                "currentAuth": ['Authentication', function(Authentication) {
                    return Authentication.$requireSignIn(); // if rejected throws $routeChangeError
                }]
            }
        })
}]);
```

Now what if I want to add a resolve to the `'/login'` route so that if the user is logged in I can just force them to the account page or a success page?

```
.when('/login', {
    controller: 'userController',
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    resolve: {
        "currentAuth": [function() {
            // reject if the user is already logged in
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.when('/login', {
    controller: 'userController',
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    resolve: {
        "currentAuth": ['$q', function($q) {
            var p = $q.defer();
            if (Authentication.$getAuth()) {
                p.reject({code: someErrorCode, message: 'Already logged in'});
            } else {
                p.resolve();
            }
            return p.promise;
        }]
    }
});
```

You should also handle the scenario when logged in, in `$routeChangeError` or `$stateChangeError`

Comment: for some reason this is making it not load my login page at all anymore, even when I'm logged out. Any idea why?

Comment: We probably shouln't use $requoreSignIn, I'll update the answer using $getAuth()

Comment: I was able to log an error that says that $getAuth() is not a function. I included my Authentication factory as well - `['$q', 'Authentication', function($q, Authentication) {}`

Comment: Nevermind! I made an error, called `Authentication` factory when I needed to call my `firebaseAuth` factory that returned `$firebaseAuth()`, thanks!